# Is it possible to load an aliased module?

Tags: module, dojo, alias, amd

I have a module "default/foo/bar" and a module "agency/foo/bar".  I setup an alias to load the agency module instead of the default module.  Yet I still want "agency/foo/bar" to load "default/foo/bar" but that's not possible because of the alias.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here's actual snippets:

```
    aliases: [
        ["gis/ol/config", "agency/ol/config"],
        ["aliased/gis/config", "gis/ol/config"]
    ],
```

Try to load the original module but it doesn't work..config is an Object:

define(["aliased/gis/config"], function (config) { // config is an object });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that using `map` instead of `aliases` is much clearer and easier to understand:

```js
map: {
  '*': {
    'gis/ol/config': 'agency/ol/config'
  },
  'agency/ol/config': {
    'gis/ol/config': 'gis/ol/config'
  }
}
```

This configuration causes all modules to load 'agency/ol/config' in place of 'gis/ol/config', except for 'agency/ol/config' which will load 'gis/ol/config' as 'gis/ol/config'.

Comment: Yes. Map can be used for the different package names.